# Can anybody explain why Compojure's routing macro only accepts literal vector as route description parameter?

Tags: clojure, compojure

compojure.core/GET accepts as a route definition parameter either a string describing a URI or a vector describing a regular expression to be matched with parameters extracted from the URI in addition to the URI itself. You can find the docs here [Routes in Detail](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail#matching-the-uri)

From my REPL (starting from scratch, leiningen's project.clj at the end of this question)

```
user> (use '[compojure.core :only [GET]])
nil
user> (def h (GET "/" [] "hello"))
#'user/h
user> (h {:uri "/" :request-method :get})
{:status 200, :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8"}, :body "hello"}
```

so far so good, plain vanilla route

what follows is an example that uses a vector for routing:

```
user> (def h2 (GET ["/foo/:id" :id #"[0-9]+"] [] "hello from foo"))
#'user/h2
user> (h2 {:uri "/foo/123" :request-method :get})
{:status 200, :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8"}, :body "hello from foo"}
user> (h2 {:uri "/foo/abc" :request-method :get})
nil
```

still all's good; you can see that it only matches requests for numerical :id's

now here comes the part I don't understand:

```
user> (def v ["/foo/:id" :id #"[0-9]+"])
#'user/v
user> (def h3 (GET v [] "hello again from foo"))
#'user/h3
user> (h3 {:uri "/foo/abc" :request-method :get})
IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :route-matches of protocol: #'clout.core/Route found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentVector  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:541)
```

**Can anybody explain the reason why the handler fails at evaluation time when it's defined with a variable instead of a literal vector?**

In case you want to replicate the exact environment, this is my leiningen project file project.clj:

```
(defproject cljlab "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that compojure's GET is a macro, not a function. Macros run at compile time, so it doesn't get to see what is the value of "v". See the difference between the code generated for h2 and h3:

```
user> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(GET ["/foo/:id" :id #"[0-9]+"] [] "hello from foo")))
      (compojure.core/make-route
      :get
      (clout.core/route-compile "/foo/:id" {:id #"[0-9]+"})
      (clojure.core/fn
         [request__1858__auto__]
         (compojure.core/let-request
           [[] request__1858__auto__]
           "hello from foo")))

user> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(GET v [] "hello again from foo")))
      (compojure.core/make-route
      :get
      (if (clojure.core/string? v) (clout.core/route-compile v) v)
      (clojure.core/fn
        [request__1858__auto__]
        (compojure.core/let-request
          [[] request__1858__auto__]
          "hello again from foo")))
```

In the first case the macro is able to split the route into its constituents and transform it. In the second case the macro just sees the "v" symbol.

Comment: This doesn't quite fully answer the question. In the second case you can see that runtime code has been compiled to handle a `v` (with globe scope) that is a string. So, why not also include a runtime test for a vector likewise and do `(route-compile (first v) (apply hash-map (rest v))`.

Comment: In other words, `(def s "/")` followed by `((GET s [] "hello") {:uri "/" :request-method :get})` works due to the runtime code compiled. So, why allow this but not the vector case?

Comment: I cannot answer why Compojure's author decided not to make the vector check at runtime, but probably is either an oversight of Compojure or was considered an unnecessary complexity

Comment: You are right we can't guess at intentions, just curious if there was an obvious reason. I inserted the runtime check and haven't found anything broken (yet). Frankly though, I was more surprised that there *is* a check for a runtime string than there not being one for vectors.

Comment: This is a little late, but this is a bug in Compojure. It should handle vectors as well as strings.